# Mongoose mysteriously ignoring a field on saving new model

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm experiencing what seems like a bug or a total oversight on my part.  I have a mongoose schema, model and new instance of the model defined as described below.  When I try to create a new event and save it, one of the fields is being totally ignored.  When I view the document in mongodb, the enddate field is not present.  My second issue is that in my req.user (which is created through passport login system), I have an object that looks like:

```
req.user:  { name:
   { firstname: 'John',
     lastname: 'Smith',
     fullname: 'John Smith' },
  _id: 5a500b3f0777ab3b28422ad2,
  username: 'XXX', etc...}}
```

Problems:

1. enddate does not get populated in the database even though it is declared in the schema and added to my newEvent.
2. I can't seem to access req.user.name.xxx to set my newEvent owner fullname, however username works.  Is this because the name properties are in a nested object?
3. Shouldn't mongoose be using my defined schema to do validation on my newEvent?

My Event schema

```
 var EventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    //  _id : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
     type: String,
     name : String,
     owner : {fullname: String, username: String},
     startdate : String,
     enddate : String,
     completeddate : String
 });
```

My code section that creates and saves the new event:

```
var newEvent = new EventModel({
    // event_id: "5a482302a469a068edc004e3",
    type: req.body.eventtype,
    name: req.body.eventname,
    owner : {fullname: req.user.name.firstname + " " + req.user.name.lastname, username: req.user.username},
    startdate: req.body.startdate,
    enddate : req.body.enddate,
    completeddate : ""
});

   newEvent.save(function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("ERROR CREATING EVENT");
            console.log(err.name + ":  " + err.message);
            res.response(err.name + ":  " + err.message);
        } else {
            console.log("SUCCESSFUL EVENT ADDITION");
            callback(result)
        }
    });
```

Comment: What does the request body look like?

Comment: `req.body:  { eventtype: 'Test',
  startdate: '2018-01-13',
  eventname: 'Test',
  createevent: 'Submit' }` Hmm... looks like the enddate is not in there... and yet I referenced.  That might have been the cause.  I changed  enddate to be "" by default and now it is being inserted.  I would have assumed it should still be inserted with a null or undefined or "" or something...

Comment: Golden rule of troubleshooting: check the inputs. 

Comment: True. Thanks for the pointer. :) But my questions are still unanswered. For point 1, removing `req.body.enddate` and defaulting to `""` solved my problem, but that doesn't answer why the field was not being populated when I referenced an undefined value.  I'm guessing Mongoose default behaviour in such cases is to ignore the field.  Points 2 and 3 still pending...  I'll keep playing around with it.